# Fancybox and doubleclick not opening gallery

Tags: javascript, fancybox

My fancybox works fine with single clicks.  It does not work on double click (I need double click). It opens the link I click, but not the full gallery.

This opens the gallery successfully:

```
$('.fancybox').click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

This unfortunately does not, only opening the specific image I click:

```
$('.fancybox').click(function() {
    return false;
}).dblclick(function() {
    $.fancybox.open($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: can you put it on jsfiddle?

Comment: Js fiddle isn't allowing me to turn off single clicks even... This is what the gallery working with single clicks looks like http://jsfiddle.net/auE2u/ I want to be able to turn off single clicks and only have that happen on double click

Comment: what version of fancybox are you using? because your jsfiddle is using v1.3.4 .... I just want to clarify because the method `$.fancybox.open()` doesn't exist in that version.

Answer (score -1):

This should work, you need to stop the default behaviour of the "a" tag

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fancybox').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }).dblclick(function (e) {
        $.fancybox.open($(this).attr('href'));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: That would (arguably) open the image but not the gallery.

Comment: it opens the gallery...its tested

Comment: Double-clicks break the gallery functionality.